# Acoustic gramophone on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat

Is it permitted to play an acoustic Gramophone on Shabbat? An acoustic gramophone is a non electric device that plays disc records by having them rotate under a point.

Comment: There's always the rabbinic issour of "שמא יתקן כלי שיר" — one may come to fix the instrument. Thus one may not play any instrument on shabbat. This may be a relevant factor to your question

Comment: If this is indeed the issour, i believe it would count. A piano works on a similar concept, where a hammer hits a string...

Comment: There is a Rabbinic halacha against using noisy appliances on Shabbos, even if they are set on a timeswitch, and I'd imagine that this would apply to this too

Comment: The non-electric Gramophones needed to be cranked up in order for them to play. Would that be like winding a mechanical clock on Shabbos?

Comment: Some opine that winding a mechanical clock on Shabbos involves תיקון מנה, which would appear to also apply to cranking the Gramophone.

Comment: SA OC 338.1, the rama, and MB say that there are also the problems of "weekday mannerisms" — ouvda dihol. As well as hishmiah kol.  The discussion there is of a door knocker. I.e a mechanical object which is not intrinsicaly musical and yet is still prohibited. A fortiori to a music making machine...

Answer (score 2):

**It is forbidden to sound musical tones on Shabbat using a musical instrument.** The issue is not about using electricity but so one does not come to fix the instrument since repairing an instrument on Shabbat is a Torah transgression -- either *boneh* (building) or *make be patish* (making an item usable).

The Rambam writes ([Hilchot Shabbat 23:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/935244/jewish/Shabbat-Chapter-Twenty-Three.htm))

> Accordingly, it is forbidden to sound musical tones on the Sabbath,
> whether using a musical instrument - e.g., a harp or a lyre - or using
> another object.

This is codified by the Shulchan Aruch in [OC 339:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.339.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in the context of clapping hands

> We do not clap nor to we slap our hand to our thighs nor do we dance.
> **This is a rabbinic decree lest one come to fix a musical instrument.**
> [...] **All of this and
> anything similar is forbidden, based on a rabbinic decree preventing
> the fixing of a musical instrument**.

Since it is forbidden to use instruments, even touching them is forbidden because of *mukz*e - either *kli shemelachto le-isur* (a utensil used for forbidden actions) or if very valuable *machmat chisaron kis* (fragile utensils).

For further reading see [here](https://ohr.edu/1980), [here](https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=2555&PageIndex=1#:%7E:text=This%20means%20that%20just%20as,resemble%20musical%20tunes%20on%20Shabbat.) and [there](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol13Issue5.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

How does the disc rotate? Probably by turning a crank, which seems no different from any number of work activities such as operating a spinning wheel or riding a bicycle. No cranks are mentioned in the Bible, so the prohibition would necessarily be rabbincal. I do not know if any rabbinical authority has specifically addressed the issue of gramaphones, but operating them by hand seem logically in involve "work."

See [this article](https://www.cbi18.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Musical-Instruments-and-Recorded-Music-on-Shabbat-and-Festivals.pdf) for some interesting rabbinical debates about the permissibility of music-listening on Shabbat.

Comment: Is spinning a wheel prohibited?

Comment: Spinning a wheel is not work. Making noise with an instrument however is generally prohibited

Comment: עבוצ- [Spinning](https://prezi.com/4nqcnhx5od5v/the-39-melachot-of-shabbat/)
One may not use a spinning wheel on Shabbat to make clothing, etc. because that would be the melacha of tying. (admittedly this does not address the gramaphone question directly.)

Comment: Please note the link in your answer refers to a Conservative "teshuva" - I'm not sure if you were aware but it is worth noting for others